# Is there any option to make get encoding return the required number of bytes matching the target byte array

Tags: c#

I have a byte array defined as

```
byte[] target;
```

Now when i call

```
target = Encoding.Ascii.GetBytes(input);
```

the returned bytes are only 3.But i need a 4 byte array.
Is there any way to get the returned 3 bytes padded with a 0 byte so that i get a byte array of length 4

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to just copy from temporary byte array:

```
byte[] target = new byte[4];
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("abc");
Array.Copy(bytes, 0, target, 1, bytes.Length);
```

Comment: oh..so there isnt any easy way to do it other than making a copy i guess.thanks for the answer

Comment: @ShaijuJanardhanan - Yes there is, Encoding.ASCII.GetEncoder().Convert has an overload that lets you write directly in an array starting from an offset

Answer (score 0):

No, because then it would be a different string from the ASCII representation of the input.  You can however copy it into the target array.

```
        byte[] target = new byte[4];
        byte[] ascii = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
        Array.Copy(ascii, target, ascii.Length);
```